# Is it possible to create a second network device with a specific name?

Tags: ip, ethernet, mac-address, ifconfig, eth0

Due to a licence server requirement I need to have an `eth0` or `eth1` named network device. However, my current configuration only has a network device named `enp8s0`. I am using a CentOS 7 linux system.

I do not want to rename my network device since this would involve serious reconfigurations of various parts of my system.

Is it possible to create a second network device in any form e.g. using `ip address`, `ip link`, `ifconfig` etc., that has the name `eth0` or `eth1` withouth changing the original network device name? It only has to have a MAC adress.

On this [site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-or-adding-new-network-alias-to-a-network-card-nic/) it is shown how to create an alias `eth0:0` of the device `eth0` but in my case I need a completly new name.

Comment: udev is your friend.

Comment: @DanilaLadner Could you please elaborate on your suggestion? I though with `udev` you modify a device!?

Comment: centos7 i think device creation had been moved back to kernel to devtmpfs
maybe this will help you http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-a-machine-without-a-physical-ad

Comment: @DanilaLadner This exactly solves my problem. If you post an answer I will accept it and grant you reputation. Thank you very much for the link!

Comment: Hey, it's no problem, man.